# Creating a new RegionManager with only current Region in it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am using PRISM to build an application.

I have several views with the same name, each of this views have a Region with the same name. For not naming evey Region different I tought about creating a new `RegionManager` for each View. 
The Problem is: As soon as I generate a new `RegionManager` it doesn't know about my current Region of my View.

`RegionMan = regionManager.CreateRegionManager();`

How can I create a new `RegionManager` with **only** the current Region of the View in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer in this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320673/Scoped-Prism-regions-Fix-for-Prism-work-item-8927